# Select a fittting model for histograms varying the number of Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, curve-fitting, histogram

I have many data in the form of one dimensional histogram, to give an example consider the data at http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=1mNRuEHZ

[image: test hist]

I expect that these data are obtained from a pdf composed of a mixture of Gaussian distributions but with their actual number being unknown.

I want then to fit these data with a model given by a mixture of Gaussians

$$
f_N(x) = \sum_{k=1}^N c_k \exp \left[ - \frac{(x-a_k)^2}{2 b_k^2} \right]
$$

where $a_k$, $b_k$, $c_k$ **and** $N$ are in principle parameters to be fitted.

The problem can be viewed as a problem of model selection between different $f_N$ for all the possible values of $N$.

My idea is then to make an usual fit by least squares at fixed $N$ and then compare the results for different $N$ via some statistical measure of the quality of the fit, as e.g. Akaike information criterion (AIC).
Is this an acceptable test?

For the data of the previous example (that I generated as a test from 3 gaussians) I will obtain

```
 N        AIC
 -------------
 1      +568.1
 2      +557.4
 3      -446.6
 4      -443.5
 5      -442.7
```

As you see, the AIC keeps slightly decreasing for $N$ larger than 3. It is clear that $N=3$ is the best choice here but I'd like to have a definite procedure to fix it.

I mention that in some cases I have more data histograms extracted from the same pdf, so I could do some cross validation. Although this always a good test, the availability of my data changes from sample to sample, so I'd prefer to have a criterion for the single histogram (if the quality of the test is not too much different).

Comment: What you appear to have is a *mixture* of Gaussians, not a *sum* (the latter would be a single / unimodal distribution).